# Do we get a speed advantage with: new String("a string") for multiple tests on that string in javaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am making a small search engine where string are searched often. Since javaScript convert a string primitive (declared like `var thatString = "a string"`) to an object when we use methods like `indexOf` on them, and then back to a primitive, I think that converting all the primitives stings to object with `var aString = new String("aString")` in the array of strings to be analysed could bring a speed advantage. But is it really worth it ?
The search engine prototype can be seen at http://bottinbio.com and it's code (open source) at http://ogfor.com/bottinbio/code.js

Comment: jsperf.com  check it and share the results

Comment: http://jsperf.com/string-primitive-vs-string-object the string primitive is 0.34% faster with firefox in ubuntu, but it should be noted that I added a property to the string Object wich is is maybe the reason for the lower speed. Of course the capability to add properties to the string Object is probably the main advantage of using the string Object.

Comment: Without the string property, the primitive is still .33% faster to search with firefox in ubuntu. I am not sure my test is done right though, trying a new test.

Comment: Still faster with primitive after editing the jsPerf test

Answer (score 1):

Even when we do not add a property to the string Object made with new String, the primitive  is much faster (43-45%) in firefox and chrome in ubuntu.
Thanks DhruvPathak for the link to jsperf.com